# Way to optimize search on cartesian plane using AVL tree

Tags: c, search, optimization, geometry, avl-tree

## Geometry problem using C language

I need to do a task of storing rectangles on a AVL tree (self-balancing tree), based on the x position on a cartesian plane to make some search functions later on (like, printing the name of the rectangles that are inside a given area)
[image: Example of the task]

My teacher recommended storing the minimum value (raw x) and the maximum value (x + width) on each node of both subtrees, in order to optimize searching on the region.

For example, in the image above, the red node (root) min value would be the x of the black rectangle, and the max value would be the x + width of the green rectangle.

The conditions the teacher gave were the following:

(PS: Please consider search_rect as the rectangle to search on the region)

1. If (current_node->left->max) >= (search_rect->x) AND (current_node->left->min) <= (search_rect->x):
   Go to the left subtree
2. If (current_node->right->max) >= (search_rect->x) AND (current_node->right->min) <= (search_rect->x):
   Go to the right subtree
3. If the whole rectangle stored on the current node is inside the search_rect, return this rectangle

Are there any other suggestions to optimize this search? I mean, like would it be easier if we compared only the x of the rectangles, instead of the min x and also the max x ?

Comment: R-Trees are probably a better choice for the structure.  However, you seem to be stuck with your teacher's design.

Comment: I don't think that using binary trees is justified. Searches would still be O(n) in the worst case. But the constant factor will be far larger.

Comment: The problem is that I need to use AVL trees, of course there are better alternatives such as R-Trees or even Kd-Trees. Do you think that is necessary to compare the maximum x value? Wouldn't be easier if I compare only the minimum value ?

Comment: As far as I see, the `node->min <= search_rect->x` condition should be `node->min <= search_rect->x + search_rect->width`. You could also store the y-bounds for each node to prune the search even more. Whether or not that makes it faster is questionable (as the tree is constructed over the x-coordinates).